# TextAlignment in iOS 6 and iOS 5

Tags: nsstring, uilabel

As you know from iOS 6 `UITextAlignment` is deprecated, but it's still can be used if you support earlier iOS versions. But I have a question how to make it text alignment for iOS 5 as `UITextAlignmentLeft` and for iOS 6 as `NSTextAlignmentJustified`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

write below statement in your common file or .pch File

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
```

then to check textalignment for ios 6 or ios 5 write

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0"))
{
  your code for ios 6.0 and above
}
else
{
   your code for earlier versions
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0"))
{
  your code for ios 6.0 and above
}
else
{
   your code for earlier versions
}
```